# Distinct Value of a column in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, distinct

Hello all I have made a query using left outer joins which result in some what like the table below:

```
| 00-00-00-00-00 | 1 | a.txt |
| 00-00-00-00-00 | 2 | b.txt |
| 00-00-00-00-00 | 1 | c.txt |
| 11-11-11-11-11 | 2 | d.txt |
```

What I want is Distict value of the MAC Column below is the SQL Fiddle to understand better.

**[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/01511/1)**

Thanks

**EDIT**

The purpose is that 2 and 3 are useless or redundant data where as 1 and 4 are useful means the 1 and 4 show the current file on the MACs

**Output:**

```
| 00-00-00-00-00 | 1 | a.txt |
| 11-11-11-11-11 | 2 | d.txt |
```

Comment: But do you want other columns also ? If yes, which FileName (for example) do you need ? If you just need Macaddress, it's just `select distinct MacAddress from Heartbeats`. Else, can do `select min(id), min(counterNo), min(FileName), MacAddress from Heartbeats
group by MacAddress`. But that's an arbitrary choice for id, filename and counterNo...

Comment: i am with @Raphaël Althaus and if you want only distinct then here is the query select distinct macaddress from Heartbeats

Comment: Yes I do want other columns the db I gave in Filldle is a sample and I want all other columns

Comment: Is aggregating an option here?

Comment: But which one do you want for mac address 00-00-00-00-00 ? you can choose 1, 1, a.txt, or 2, 1, b.txt, or 3, 1, c.txt or any other combination... See for example :http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a75e47/42

Comment: @Rafay, tell us more about your purpose.

Comment: Well, just show us the desired result for your 4 lines.

Comment: @Sohail Question edited

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus output added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get only the distinct macaddresses, you can do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT macaddress FROM heartbeats
```

If you want all the columns alongside the distinct macaddress, you need to create a rule to get them. The query below gives you the ones with the highest id for each macaddress:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM heartbeats t1
LEFT JOIN heartbeats t2
    ON (t1.macaddress = t2.macaddress AND t1.id < t2.id)
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a75e47/24)</kbd>

**EDIT:**

Since in original query the code used doesnt have ID column the above query was refined as:

```
with cte as (
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (Select 0)) AS ID,* from heartBeats
)


SELECT t1.*
FROM cte t1
LEFT JOIN cte t2
    ON (t1.macaddress = t2.macaddress AND t1.id < t2.id)
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/01511/2)

Comment: Yes it correct if I have ID, but in original query which i have to use in code it does not have id, can I use row number ?

Answer (score 4):

Is not possible to answer exactly what you ask. However, usually folk that express the question you ask really mean to ask something like 'I want all the columns for a sample of rows containing only distinct MacAddress values'. This question has many answers, as the result is non-deterministic. A trivial solution is to pick the first (for whatever definition of 'first') row for each MacAddress:

```
with cte as (
  select row_number() over (partition by MacAddress order by CounterNo) as rn, *
             from Heartbeats
  )
select * from cte where rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT hb1.* FROM [heartbeats] as hb1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN [heartbeats] as hb2   
       ON (hb1.macaddress = hb2.macaddress AND hb1.id > hb2.id) 
         WHERE hb2.id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to neglect the file name. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a75e47/13